# Properly import a class in BlueJ

Tags: java, class, import, bluej

I've used JDatePicker for  a simple app, but my teacher said that he will accept no precompiled .jar's, and he needs to see how it's able to compile from just sources.
So I checkout JDatePicker source code, extract it, and add every `.java` file from the extracted directory to my BueJ project. I had to remove some imports inside those extracted classes, so that JVM will "look inside project".
Now BlueJ can not find where classes `JDatePickerImpl` & `JDatePanelImpl` are defined...
And neither can I. If I `grep -rn` through project folder all I get is two lines of my own code.
Can anybody suggest how to import classes that are supposed to be there, just can't find definitions? Maybe, I should write an "implementation" (hence the `Impl` in name)?

Here's [uploaded project](https://github.com/mekkanizer/TrainTicket)
The only file written by me is `TrainTicket.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the source code of JDatePickerImpl in your project because it's missing. You need to extract it or get it from sites like grepcode.com, e.g. for [JDatePickerImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jdatepicker/jdatepicker/1.3.4/org/jdatepicker/impl/JDatePickerImpl.java#JDatePickerImpl).

Comment: Thanks, I have removed all errors in code by downloading those files one by one and replacing them in proj... However now it works only partially, even though no compile errors. Can you suggest how to dowanload all .jar contents from that site?

Comment: Just click on the version number 1.3.4 at the top where you get an overview and can download the whole source code in a jar. http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jdatepicker/jdatepicker/1.3.4/